# With Hibernate, how can I query a table and return a hashmap with key value pair id>name?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I've got this table :

```
table name : Account
Fields : id (varchar), name(varchar), other fields...
```

I want to query this table with hibernate mechanism (to use the second cache level). The result of the hibernate query must be a hash map where the key is the field id and where the value is the field name.

How can I write it with HQL ?

If I use map, I can only use alias and if I use a constructor with an object, I must transform result to hashmap which is time consuming.

```
Example : 
Id | name | other fields
1 Jerome ...
2 Steve ...
3 Nick ...
```

the result of the query must be a hashmap :

```
1>Jerome
2>Steve
3>Nick
```

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question is old but this might still help other people.
You can now use HQL to return maps with hibernate.
Use something like this:

```
select new map( max(bodyWeight) as max, min(bodyWeight) as min, count(*) as n ) from Cat cat
```

From hibernate docs:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select

Comment: about 1 year 1/2, I update my accepted answer ! This was exactly what I was searched for. This is a bit too late but a useful information !

Comment: @JeromeCance And 7 years later I'm here wondering why this is the accepted answer...how do you map the ID to the name? This is just mapping the aliases to the selected values.

Answer (score 5):

I think the closest you can get is to use this query:

```
select id, name from Account
```

which'll give you a result set of two length arrays. You'll have to build the map manually, like so:

```
for(Object[] row : rs) {
    map.put(row[0], row[1]);
}
```

Note that this will largely ignore the second level cache and get translated into a SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

Default entity mode of Hibernate is EntityMode.POJO.

you can use EntityMode.MAP entity mode for retrieving the query output in Map format.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels

Answer (score 0):

Assuming for the moment that Account doesn't have any non-lazy associations that would be loaded, the following is just the best you're going to get, performance-wise:

```
List<Account> accounts = (List) session.createQuery("from Account").list();
for (Account account : accounts) map.put(account.getID(), account.getName());
```

This may be "time consuming" but it's not like Hibernate can somehow magically avoid the step of putting each returned row into a map.

Unlike the other answer, this should benefit from the second-level cache.

Answer (score 0):

Hiii...

Below code might help you.

```
    Query query = session.createQuery("select id, name from table");
    List results = query.list();
```

To display the results as objects does work:

```
    int i;
    int j;
    Object object = null;
    for (i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println("-------");
        Object[] obj = (Object[]) results.get(i);
        for (j=0;j<obj.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(obj[j]);
        }
        System.out.println("-------");

    }
```

Edit : You can use that results objects as map and you'r done.

Answer (score -1):

intead of using default entity name you can applied the entity-name to hbm.xml file.

for Example

using this, hibernate give the key/value pair that means return the map.