# getting all date values in a date range in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to know how do I get all dates in a date range in Hibernate query resultset.

It should be something similar to the following pseudo code in SQL

> Select "ALL DATES" from ???? where date between
>   TO_DATE('date-val','format') and TO_DATE('date-val','format').

It may require some different logic but if I give a range like 5-Feb-2011 to 2-March-2011
it should return me all dates in that range in the resultset...
i.e

> resultset = 5-Feb-2011, 6-Feb-2011,..... 28-Feb-2011, 1-March-2011,
>   2-March-2011

**Update:**
the following query is in Oracle gives the required result set

```
select 
    d.dateInRange as dateval,
    eventdesc,
    nvl(td.dist_ucnt, 0) as dist_ucnt
from (
    select 
        to_date('03-NOV-2011','dd-mon-yyyy') + rownum - 1 as dateInRange
    from all_objects
    where rownum <= to_date('31-DEC-2011','dd-mon-yyyy') - to_date('03-NOV-2011','dd-mon-yyyy') + 1
) d
left join (
    select 
        currentdate,
        count(distinct(grauser_id)) as dist_ucnt,
        eventdesc 
    from
        txn_summ_dec

    group by currentdate, eventdesc 
) td on td.currentdate = d.dateInRange order by d.dateInRange asc

Resultset:
Date                    eventdesc       dist_cnt
2011-11-03 00:00:00     null                0
and so on..
2011-11-30 00:00:00     null                0
2011-12-01 00:00:00     Save Object         182
....
2011-12-31 00:00:00     null                0
```

Comment: You really need to do this with Hibernate? Sounds like a job for Java logic unrelated to persistence. Standard API [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) or [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) would both fit the requirements well.

Comment: I can use Java too, just to clear the purpose of this, finally I want to do a left join on this resultset with my distinct count of users between the range, grouped by date , so that I havecounts on all dates in the resultset (even if theres no count on a date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic should take care of generating the range:

```
public static List<Date> dayRange(Date begin, Date end) {
    if (end.before(begin)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid range");
    }

    final List<Date> range = new ArrayList<>();
    final Calendar c1 = extractDate(begin);
    final Calendar c2 = extractDate(end);

    while (c1.before(c2)) {
        range.add(c1.getTime()); // begin inclusive
        c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    range.add(c2.getTime()); // end inclusive

    return range;
}

private static Calendar extractDate(Date date) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    c.setTime(date);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    return c;
}
```

Not as pretty and terse as Joda Time, but gets you going.

If all you need is to display your query results with zeroes for dates without results, run the original query grouped by date (without the left join) and later fill in missing dates. Assuming that your query returns a `Map<String, Long>`:

```
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);

final Date begin = df.parse("5-Feb-2011");
final Date end = df.parse("2-March-2011");

final List<Date> range = dayRange(begin, end);
final Map<String, Long> result = // code to execute your query

for (Date date: range) {
    String key = df.format(date);
    if(!result.containsKey(key)) {
        result.put(key, 0l);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is a good framework but its missing the most important part - "code to execute the query" . Right now I have managed to figure the Oracle based Query to get the required result directly in the resultset - no need to have any code to modify the resultset, now just need to convert it to HQL/criteria api! please check the update on the post

Comment: @pri_dev, my angle here is that you don't need the first half of the query. Just execute the second half - after the left join (if you have problems mapping this to HQL, read [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping)), extract the result to a Map (if you have problems extracting the result to a Map read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736743/with-hibernate-how-can-i-query-a-table-and-return-a-hashmap-with-key-value-pair)) and use my code to add missing dates. Do this clear it up?

Comment: Ok :). Just to clear it up, you need the second half of the query plus to filter the dates with something like `between startDate and endDate`. The results should be extract to a data structure such as `TreeMap<Date, Object[]>` or `TreeMap<Date, MyCustomObjectForDescAndCount>`. My code can then be used to put missing `date -> [null desc, 0 count]` pairs in the map.