# How to return HashMap from JPA query?

Tags: jpa

I want to return a HashMap from JPA query like the below but I don't know how to fill the HashMap from this query. Actually I want to fill charts from HashMap in the frontend

```
public HashMap<String,String> getCount(Date start,Date end) {
           HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
            Query q = 
                  em.createQuery(
                    "select count(i.uuid),i.username from Information i where i.entereddt between :start and :end group by i.username");
                q.setParameter("start",new Timestamp(start.getTime()));
                q.setParameter("end",new Timestamp(end.getTime()));

                 System.out.println(" query"+ q.getResultList().get(0).toString());

             return map;
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you intend to populate the map?  Using `(count, username)` as pairs?

Comment: Yes with username as key and count as value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Hibernate, how can I query a table and return a hashmap with key value pair id>name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736743/with-hibernate-how-can-i-query-a-table-and-return-a-hashmap-with-key-value-pair)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears that you were trying to execute a query which return types not mapped to any Java entities you have (or if they be present you never mentioned them).  In this case, you want to use `createNativeQuery()`, which will return a `List` of type `Object[]`.

Try using this version of the method:

```
public HashMap<String,String> getCount(Date start,Date end) {
    HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
                    "select count(i.uuid),i.username from Information i" +
                    "where i.entereddt between :start and :end group by i.username");
    q.setParameter("start",new Timestamp(start.getTime()));
    q.setParameter("end",new Timestamp(end.getTime()));

    List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();

    for (Object[] result : list) {
        map.put(result[0].toString(), result[1].toString());
    }

    return map;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I replaced the parameters with ? (?start and ?end ) and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Please refer, [JPA 2.0 native query results as map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595328/jpa-2-0-native-query-results-as-map/46190527#46190527)

In your case in `Postgres`, it would be something like,

```
List<String> list = em.createNativeQuery("select cast(json_object_agg(count(i.uuid),i.username) as text) from schema.information i where i.entereddt between :start and :end group by i.username")
                   .setParameter("start",new Timestamp(start.getTime()))
                   .setParameter("end",new Timestamp(end.getTime()))
                   .getResultList();

//handle exception here, this is just sample
Map map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(list.get(0), Map.class);
```

Kindly note, I am just sharing my workaround with Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's an old question, but you can create an object to store info

```
public class UserCount {
   private String username;
   private Long count;

   public UserCount(String user, Long count){
      this.username = user;
      this.count = count;
   }

}
```

It's important to create the constructor and to pass the parameters in the correct way.

The JPQL became

```
select my.package.UserCount(i.username, count(i.uuid) ) from schema.information i where i.entereddt between :start and :end group by i.username
```

The query returns a `List<UserCount>` .