# How to avoid specifying SQL query on Spring Data JPA when an attribute comes from another table

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working with Spring Data JPA and I have the following entities:
Country: {country_id, country_name}
Region: {region_id, region_name, country_id}

There is a onetomany relationship from Country to Region.

I have a JpaRepository for Country and I have a method like the following:

```
@Query("SELECT new org.example.CountryDTO(a.countryId, a.countryName, b.regionName ) FROM Country AS a left join Region AS lpd on a. countryId = r. countryId  WHERE a. countryId = LOWER(:country) and r.regionName= LOWER(:region) ”)
List<CountryDTO> find(@Param("country") String country, @Param("region") String region);
```

The question is, is there any way to avoid having to specify an SQL query? Ideally I would like to do something like:

```
List<CountryDTO> findByCountryAndRegionName(@Param("country") String country, @Param("region") String region);
```

However, that seems a bit complicated because the region_name column comes from the Region table.

Has anybody done anything like that? Any elegant solution that you might propose?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please reformat your question: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you can define constraints by traversing nested properties. See [2.4.3 Property Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

Assuming Country has a property `regions` and both Country and Region have `name` properties, you may write something like : `List<Country> findByNameAndRegions_Name(String countryName, String regionName)`

Comment: Hi @sébastien-helbert Thank you for your suggestion. Question for you here, is it necessary to have one repository for Country and one for Region? I ask you this because since all the queries I will create are only related to Country at this moment I do not have a repository for Region. The other question would be, does this work without relationships?

Comment: If all queries are related to Country only you don't need a Region Repository. About relationships, as far as I know, it won't work without relationships because nested paths rely on relationship names / rely on properties names.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
interface CountryProjection {
  String getCountryId();
  String getCountryName()
  String getRegionName()
}
```

and then your query method can look like this:

```
List<CountryProjection> findByCountryNameAndRegionRegionNameAllIgnoreCase(String country,String region);
```

You must be using `Spring Data JPA 1.10` a later for projection support in query methods.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can return a `List<Object[]>` if you use a native query, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31823948/1763011).

Although I would prefer creating a separate DTO as this is a different projection.