# how can i return map as jpa query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a problem.
how can i return map as query in jpa ?

```
Map<string, User> userMap = em.createQuery("select new map(u.id, *) 
from user u"
```

I want to return map as query but I don't know how to. 

and I don`t want to return map using to iterate list. like as the below
[How to return HashMap from JPA query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823778/how-to-return-hashmap-from-jpa-query)
can someone help me ?
in advance thank you.

Comment: You can't. You can return keys/values and then put them into a Map yourself ... aka trivial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Hibernate, how can I query a table and return a hashmap with key value pair id>name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736743/with-hibernate-how-can-i-query-a-table-and-return-a-hashmap-with-key-value-pair)

Comment: You are doing correct, just this HQL will return List of map For Eg. `List<Map<Integer, String>>`

Comment: @NeilStockton Thakyou for answer. By the way Is this not possible in hibernate, not in jpa?

Comment: @Amogh Thank you for your answer. Can this be used as a list only? is this  imposible to use hashmap ?

Comment: I guess yes, either in only list otherwise list of map

Comment: If you are using java 8 then you can conver List to Map. [More](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-convert-list-to-map/)

Comment: @Amogh can you see url address is example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a map list at least, which means list cannot be mapped to single map.